# How Java Println work in evaluating special symbols and arithmetic operations?

Tags: java, postfix-notation, infix-notation, arithmetic-expressions, single-quotes

The output of the following Java code is not understood.
Can anyone please tell me how is it working??

```
int i=5;
System.out.println(i+'+');// Output is 48
System.out.println(i+'-');// Output is 50
System.out.println(i+'*');// Output is 47
System.out.println(i+'%');// Output is 42
System.out.println(i+'/');// Output is 52
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with `println()`. The rules are the ordinary rules of Java.

Comment: You might want to pick an answer and mark it as the solution (green checkmark).

Answer (score 1):

The `char` data type is a single `16-bit Unicode` character.The value of `+` is `43`.

So,

```
System.out.println(i+'+'); //prints 48
```

`Java` defines `type promotion rules` that apply to *expressions*.

First, all **byte**, **short** and **char** values are promoted to **int**. Then if one of the operand is **long**, the whole expression is promoted to **long**.

Comment: Not *ASCII*, UTF-16. But yes. Could use explanation of why `int + char` is `int`.

Comment: Does it mean when we use '+' operator to add/concatenate an integer and a char we get integer value? Just like String and other data types used with '+' operator becomes String.

Comment: `char` is promoted to its `int` equivalent in an expression and then the operation is performed.

Answer (score 1):

Your best friend is the JLS:

> 15.18.2. Additive Operators (+ and -) for Numeric Types
>
> > The binary + operator performs addition when applied to two operands
> >     of numeric type, producing the sum of the operands.
> >
> > Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands (§5.6.2).

To explain "operands of numeric type":

> 4.2. Primitive Types and Values
>
> > The numeric types are the integral types and the floating-point types.
> >
> > The integral types are byte, short, int, and long, ... and **char, whose values are 16-bit unsigned integers representing UTF-16 code units** (§3.1).

And to explain "Binary numeric promotion":

> 5.6.2. Binary Numeric Promotion
>
> > When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of operands, each of which must denote a value that is convertible to a numeric type, the following rules apply, in order:
> >
> > 1. If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing
> >        conversion (§5.1.8).
> > 2. Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either
> >        or both operands as specified by the following rules:
> >
> >    If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to
> >        double.
> >
> >    Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted
> >        to float.
> >
> >    Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted
> >        to long.
> >
> >    **Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.**

(emphasis mine)

Since your int and char are numeric types they undergo binary numeric conversion, which converts the char to an int using UTF-16.

Answer (score 0):

[ASCII - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

See the above link to learn more about ASCII codes.

The expression

> (i+'+')

evaluates to (i+43), as '+' is being treated as a character here it is converted to it's corresponding ASCII code(which happens to be 43) when added to an integer i, which is equal to 5.

The rest goes without saying that 5+43 = 48.

This is called implicit casting in java.

See [widening primitive conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2).